# Tranpose of matrix that is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $X\in \mathbb{R^a}$, and $L\in\mathbb{R}^{b-a}$ which is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^b$ , where  $0<a\leq b$. Now let $Y=\{y_1,...,y_b\}$ be a $a\times b$ matrix, where $y_1,...,y_b$ is a basis for $L^{\perp}$. Define $Z=Y^T X$.

Show that $Z=0 \Rightarrow X\in L$ .

We have $Z=0 \Rightarrow Y^TX=0$. Now since the elements in $Y$ is a basis for $L^{\perp}$, can i then use this conclude that $X\in L$?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
Y^Tx = \pmatrix{y_1 & \cdots & y_b}^Tx = \pmatrix{y_1^Tx\\ \vdots \\ y_b^Tx}
$$
Now, if all of these entries are $0$, how do we conclude that $x \in L$?

Comment: Is it because $y_1$ is a basis for $L^{\perp}$? Then if $y_1^T x=0$ it is not in $L^{\perp}$, thus it has to be in $L$?

Comment: Of course the important piece of information is that the $y_i$ form a basis for $L^\perp$.  However, the statement "it is not in $L^\perp$, thus it has to be in $L$" is not correct.